# Java: Dynamic List Type to cast Json array

Tags: java, android, json, reflection

Well, I have this:
A number of webservices, each webservice returns an array of one entity. Good!

In my Android app, I call the webservices and get the Json String with the array of elements.

To make it some dynamically I made an array with the cast classes names, example:

```
<item>com.company.package.Person</item>
<item>com.company.package.Animal</item>
<item>com.company.package.Thing</item>
// etc
```

The idea was:

1. Load the array with the name of the class to cast the JSON

   ```
   String[] entities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.classNames);
   ```
2. Get a Class type with `Class.forName(...)`

   ```
   Class<?> object = Class.forName(entities[y]);
   ```
3. Always the webservices returns an array, then I want to convert the Json to Java List like this

   ```
   //see the **object**, this was my idea but doesn't work
   Type type = new TypeToken<List<**object**>() {}.getType();
   List<**object**> array = gson.fromJson(jsonArrayString, type);
   ```

Any way to do this?

**This works**

I found a way to do it

Write my own `ParameterizedType` list (@ andersschuller answer) and with this

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(entities[y]);
Type type = new ParameterizedTypeList(clazz.newInstance().getClass());
List<? extends Object> array = SystemUtils.factoryGson().fromJson(datos.get(y).toString(), type);
```

Solved my problem with 3 lines (maybe less than this)

Hope help anyone!

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, but you don't need a Type for deserializing json stuff. you can also use regular classes. see [link](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class))

Comment: Also, [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) implements [Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no way to do what you are trying to do with the `TypeToken`. However, GSON can in fact handle any [`ParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) being passed into the `gson.fromJson` method, and it is relatively straightforward to implement this interface.

In your specific case, we want to build a type whose raw type is `List`, and whose type argument is either `Person`, `Animal` or `Thing`. The following class allows us to build such types:

```
public static class ListType implements ParameterizedType {
    private final Class<?> elementClass;

    public ListType(Class<?> elementClass) {
        this.elementClass = elementClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[]{elementClass};
    }

    @Override
    public Type getRawType() {
        return List.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Assuming we then have some JSON like

```
String json = "[{\"name\": \"Charlie\"}]";
```

and `Person` and `Animal` classes that have a "name" property, we can then deserialize this JSON into lists by using an appropriate `ListType` instance:

```
List<Person> people = gson.fromJson(json, new ListType(Person.class));
System.out.println(people.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName());            // prints Person
System.out.println(people.get(0).name);                                  // prints Charlie

List<Animal> animals = gson.fromJson(json, new ListType(Animal.class));
System.out.println(animals.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName());           // prints Animal
System.out.println(animals.get(0).name);                                 // prints Charlie
```

Comment: I don't want to have to write the class name (`Person`), I want to load the argument type using `Class.forName("class.name")` (or something like this) and inject dynamically. I have many types of Objects and I want to solve my problem with no more than 5 lines :) (If is this posible)

Comment: You can simply pass the dynamically loaded class into the `ListType` constructor. Of course, you won't be able to know what type it is at compile time, so you will have `List<?> objects = gson.fromJson(json, new ListType(Class.forName("...")))`

Comment: I have made something, more lines: `Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(entities[y]);` and the `Type` like this `Type type = new ParameterizedTypeList(clazz.newInstance().getClass());` and it works.